# How to use fill_between with a colormap to fill the background of a 2d plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a simple 2d plot from a 3 column data sets e.g. y=f(x) and z=f(x). I want to plot xy and would like to display z using color. For example, the rectangular regions between [x1,x2, min(y), max(y)] ... will be filled by a background color depending on the value of z. I tried to use fill_between but could not associate a colormap with it. I'm new to matplotlib and python. I would very much appreciate your comments/suggestions.

Edit: I don't have an accurate plot but I'll try to explain my query with the help of following figure   [sample plot](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_examples/pylab_examples/fill_between_demo_02.png)

say between x=0.5 to x=1, z=1
            x=1.0, to x=1.5, z=2 ....

so I would like to cover x=0.5 to x=1 (min(y) to max(y)] with some color that corresponds to z=1, and between x=1, x=1.5, z=2 and so on.. I want to show this variation using a colormap and to display this colorbar at the right side.

Comment: Could you please post some of the code you have?  It would help us in answering your question.  And if you had some pictures of what you _would_ want your plot to look like, that would help immensely as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sound to me like you should use `contourf`

http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contourf_demo.html

This would take `x` as some dependant variable, produce `y = y(x)` and `z = z(x)`. It seems that your `z` is not dependant on `y` but contourf can still handle this.

As a simple example:

```
import pylab as plt
x = plt.linspace(0,2,100)
y = plt.linspace(0,10,100)

z = [[plt.sinc(i) for i in x] for j in y]

CS = plt.contourf(x, y, z, 20, # \[-1, -0.1, 0, 0.1\],
                        cmap=plt.cm.rainbow)
plt.colorbar(CS)
plt.plot(x,2+plt.sin(y), "--k")
```

The are many variations but hopefully this captures the elements you are looking for

[image]

Comment: many thanks for your reply. I was exactly looking for this kind of plot only. However, when I tried to run your code, I got an error message: "unexpected character after line continuation character". Another point I would like to ask, how to convert the z array in a 2d array for the following example e.g. x=[1,2,3,4,5], y=[1,2,3,4,5] and z=[2,4,6,8,10]. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hi, I fixed the errors it should work now thanks for pointing that out. In general the number of points in Z needs to be equal to `len(x) * len(y)` (the `len` gives the length). If you just want to have each row of `z` the same then `z=[[1, 4, 6, 8, 10] for i in range(len(x))]` should do the trick (or something similar). In general these problems always require a pen and paper write it out like a matrix

Comment: While this provides a solution to another problem, this doesn't answer the question summarized in the current title: *how to use fill_between with a colormap to fill the background of a 2d plot?*, hence is a dead end followed by search engines. Either the question should be updated, or the answer should provide elements both to answer the title, and to help the OP restating their actual problem.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the solution those who want cannot use contourf or need fill_between for some other reason (as in this case with irregular grid data).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import randint, sample
import matplotlib.colorbar as cbar

# from Numeric import asarray
%matplotlib inline

# The edges of 2d grid
# Some x column has varying rows of y (but always the same number of rows) 
# z array that corresponds a value in each xy cell

xedges = np.sort(sample(range(1, 9), 6))
yedges = np.array([np.sort(sample(range(1, 9), 6)) for i in range(5)])
z = np.random.random((5,5))

f, ax = plt.subplots(1, sharex=True, figsize=(8,8))
f.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)
ax.set_ylabel(r'y')
ax.set_xlabel(r'x')
ax.set_ylim(0,10)
ax.set_xlim(0,10)

c = ['r','g','b','y','m']

normal = plt.Normalize(z.min(), z.max())
cmap = plt.cm.jet(normal(z))

# plot showing bins, coloured arbitrarily.
# I want each cell coloured according to z.
for i in range(len(xedges)-1):
    for j in range(len(yedges)):
        ax.vlines(xedges[i],yedges[i][j],yedges[i][j+1],linestyle='-')
        ax.hlines(yedges[i][j],xedges[i],xedges[i+1],linestyle='-')
        ax.vlines(xedges[i+1],yedges[i][j],yedges[i][j+1],linestyle='-')
        ax.hlines(yedges[i][j+1],xedges[i],xedges[i+1],linestyle='-')

        ax.fill_between([xedges[i],xedges[i+1]],yedges[i][j],yedges[i][j+1],facecolor=cmap[i][j][:])


cax, _ = cbar.make_axes(ax) 
cb2 = cbar.ColorbarBase(cax, cmap=plt.cm.jet,norm=normal)
```

This gives

[image: x-y grid, coloured as function of z]